# Email Send Definition Key - Data Extract - Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, data-extract

I want to perform a data extract activity so that I can pull subscriber-level data regarding a particular send that occurred more than 6 months ago (no data views).

The send in question occurred in Journey Builder. When I go to JB and I look at the triggeredsenddefinition, I see '50854'. When I go to the data extract activity, I see the following options to help specify the data:

'Send IDs'
'Email Send Definition External Key'
'ListID'.

I thought that the triggeredsenddefinition in JB (Screenshot) equaled the 'Email Send Definitional External Key'. However, when I extract, I get a blank file.

Is there a unique number/designator per email send that corresponds to something in the Data Extract Activity? The only solution i can think of is to create a unique list per email send, then utilize that ListID in each activity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're entering an EmailSendDefinition external key. This is different from the TriggeredSendDefinition external key. Do you know the JobID(s) involved? If so, place these in the "Send IDs" field of the form.

Comment: I saw that as well @Macca and did so, and still didn't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Tracking Extract with External Key does not work for Journey Builder sends. However, the workaround is to run based on Date range and filter out the output for the specific Triggered Send External Key.

KI - https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwyjAAC/standard-tracking-extract-not-sent-extract-extract-by-sendid-parameter-ignored